# DatePicker correct date with only date extracted

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift2, xcode7-beta6

the below post answered half of my question, but I still need to extract only the date without the time of the corrected date, would you kindly help me guys:
[xcode in swift datepicker picks wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27891646/xcode-in-swift-datepicker-picks-wrong-date/33487759?noredirect=1#comment54769208_33487759)

Comment: datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

Answer (score 0):

I could finally find a function that combines using locale time and getting the short format of the date only. below is what I used.

```
    @IBAction func DateChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {



    let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter.localizedStringFromDate(DatePicker.date, dateStyle: NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle, timeStyle: .NoStyle)



    print(" Date: " + dateFormatter)

}
```