# swift 4 datepicker returns wrong date time

Tags: ios, datepicker, swift4

Please refer attached sample image in `datepicker`.

I already changed to today 2 26 PM

but you can notice debug mode still show 1 hour later than what I chose

```
2018-01-22 03:26:10 +0000
```

Any idea what it is?

[Attached sample image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbCaD.jpg)

Comment: date has no proper format, you need to convert based on your need

Comment: See this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/27891874/3901620

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `TimeZone` for your `DateFormatter` like this.

```
 let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
 dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(abbreviation: "GMT")// Set your time time zone here
 dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
 dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
```

Comment: Why would you want to set the timezone to GMT? That's already the issue. Using `print` on a `Date` shows the date in GMT and that is what the OP doesn't want. Don't set any timezone on the date formatter so the date shows in the user's current timezone. And avoid using `dateFormat`. Use `dateStyle` and `timeStyle`.